# Vaadin - Make FlexLayout use the full page size after wrap

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I use a FlexLayout to make my webapp wrap components on smaller displays. This FlexLayout is created as follows:

```
    FlexLayout loginLayout = new FlexLayout();
    loginLayout.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
    loginLayout.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    loginLayout.setWidthFull();
    loginLayout.add(image, hl);
    loginLayout.setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.BETWEEN);
    loginLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
```

*image* is a simple image and *hl* is a *HorizontalLayout* that holds two buttons (login, registration).

When I am on a large screen, the layout renders fine as shown in the image below.
[image: Large screen variant]

When I am on a mobile device the layout wraps as expected (see image below).

[image]

But here is the catch: I'd like to change the JustifyContentMode to CENTER after the wrap.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.